# Generic error in visualbasic.net

Tags: vb.net, system.drawing

How do I fix this error with the code below in visual basic.net using visual basic express?
Not supported exception was unhandled after 3 loops.
"       PictureBox1.Image.Save(dtmTestX, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)"

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim dtmTest As Date
    dtmTest = TimeValue(Now)
    Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    Dim dtmTestSaveLocation As String
    dtmTestSaveLocation = "D:\test" + dtmTest + ".jpg"

    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    PictureBox1.Image = screenshot

    PictureBox1.Image.Save(dtmTestSaveLocation, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
End Sub
```

Comment: What is exactly the error message you get?

Comment: The filename is going to contain the ":" character from the DateTime to string conversion.  That is not a valid character in a filename.

Comment: A generic error occurred in GDI+. PictureBox1.Image.Save(dtmTestSaveLocation, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line:

```
PictureBox1.Image.Save(dtmTestX, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

to:

```
PictureBox1.Image.Save(dtmTestSaveLocation, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

You should also really embed your graphics elements in using tags to ensure they are properly disposed:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Try
        Dim dtmTest As Date
        Dim bounds As Rectangle
        Dim dtmTestSaveLocation As String

        dtmTest = TimeValue(Now)
        dtmTestSaveLocation = "D:\test" & dtmTest.ToShortTimeString.Replace(":", "_") & ".jpg"

        bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
        Using screenshot As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
            Using graph As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
                graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
                PictureBox1.Image = screenshot
                screenshot.Save()
                PictureBox1.Image.Save(dtmTestSaveLocation, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch theException As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(theException.ToString)
        ' Note: In production code, you would want to do something useful with the exception 
        ' here, such as showing it to the user in a messagebox or writing it to a log
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full exception text and stack trace. You can get this information by wrapping the text in a try/catch block and using the exception's tostring method to write everything to the console. If you need, I can update the answer to show this code.

Comment: PictureBox1.Image.Save(dtmTestSaveLocation, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) - NotSupportedException was unhandled - The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: The problem is that when you include the time in the file name, it contains colons (`:`) which is an invalid character in a file name. I have modified the answer to replace the colons with underscores. This should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks - a few loops later... A generic error occurred in GDI+.   PictureBox1.Image.Save(dtmTestSaveLocation, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

Comment: hmm... this seems like a pretty common, nasty error. Maybe try not assigning to PictureBox1 and just saving screenshot directly?

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how to do this. When you debug the application, the exception will be printed to the `Output` window in visual studio.